# Read signal from USB mouse on an Arduino ?

Tags: usb, hardware, arduino-micro

I've got a project where I'd need to read my mouse's signal. My mouse is a G700S (so USB) and the thing was I don't really know how to do and even if it's feasible.
I'm using an Arduino Micro and my initial idea was to get a PS/2 to USB Adapter (I already have one) and then to plug it to something like [this](http://www.dx.com/p/ps-2-keyboard-adapter-module-for-arduino-works-with-official-arduino-boards-324893#.VX6FnfntlBc) wired to my Arduino. 
So my question basically is "will it work ? and if not, why ?"

The main idea is not to use USB (like an USB Host Shield) because Arduino doesn't have any USB mouse driver.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You won't be able to operate a USB peripheral without something that can act as a USB host controller.  USB host "shields" are not cost effective, but there are options out there which both have USB host ports and are far better embedded computers than an Arduino, at lower price.  Both the KL25Z and KL46Z freedom boards can do this, as can the STM32F4 Nucleos, and likely some others.  In the KL25Z case the chip itself actually costs a few cents less than an ATmega238p, and has twice the flash and four times the RAM. But you will be using a traditional toolchain or mbed.org rather than Arduino.

Comment: Is there any way to discuss with you about this ?

Answer (score 3):

This would be possible **only** if the mouse actually supports PS/2. USB to PS/2 adapters are entirely passive, and in order to function it requires that the controller in the mouse is designed to communicate in both protocols. Modern mice, especially wireless ones don't tend to have this capability anymore as PS/2 is all but a dead standard.

Comment: Mmh ok so I should try if my mouse works with the adapter prior to buying the stuff for the Arduino, right ?

Comment: @ThomasKowalski Yes. I would see if you can find a datasheet for your mouse (or at least a spec sheet) which should tell you its capabilities.

Comment: Well I tried to find a datasheet or something but I didn't find anything on Google. And I didn't find anything about backwards compatibility for PS/2. Anyway it's [there](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g700s-rechargeable-wireless-gaming-mouse) if it can help.

Comment: I would say it's "unlikely" at best.  Better to buy a cheap PS/2 mouse and have done with it.